# DynaForm Primefaces extensions gather submitted data

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am using DynaForm in Primefaces extensions. I have generated a dynamic form, but the problem is how to recover the submitted data from the controller.

Here is how I am generating my form:

this is the controller side

```
    model = new DynaFormModel();  

    DynaFormRow row;

    allfieldMessageList=getAllfieldMessageList();

    for(FilledMessageField f:allfieldMessageList)
    {
        // 1. row  
        row = model.createRegularRow();  
        FilledMessageField fmf=new FilledMessageField();
        DynaFormLabel label11 = row.addLabel(fmf.getField().getName());  
        DynaFormControl control12 = row.addControl(fmf, "input");  
        label11.setForControl(control12);  
    }
```

and this is the web page side:

```
<h:form id="addMessageIDForm" rendered="true">
        <pe:dynaForm id="dynaForm" value="#{messageValuesController.model}" 
            var="data" widgetVar="dynaFormWidget" >     
            <pe:dynaFormControl type="input" for="txt" >
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{data.value}"
                    required="#{data.required}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
            </pe:dynaFormControl>
        </pe:dynaForm>
       <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{messageValuesController.saveMessageTemplate}" process="dynaForm"  />  
</h:form>
```

Please does any one have any idea about this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the [Primefaces Extensions Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/dynaform/advancedFeatures.jsf;jsessionid=1419c44na1s6y1fck1et7pb3gi), something like this will do the trick:

```
List<FilledMessageField> fields = new ArrayList<FilledMessageField>();  
for (DynaFormControl dynaFormControl : model.getControls())  
    if (dynaFormControl.getData() instanceof FilledMessageField)
        fields.add((FilledMessageField) dynaFormControl.getData());
```

But just out of curiosity, why do you iterate over `FilledMessageField f:allfieldMessageList`, if you don't use `f`? You may aswell just take a `List< FilledMessageField>` and add your model items to it, when populating the DynaForm controls, so you won't need to pull it out of the model with rather costly `instanceof` checks.

**Note:**
Also using `DynaForm` for an input only form seems like an overkill for me. You may just use a simple `<ui:repeat>` with `<p:inputText>`s inside, using your `fields` list as your backing collection.

Comment: Thank you for you answer,

well about the variable thing it was just a copying mistake.

I think I have found my problem, the postconstructer function get called and re-initialize my model whenever I submit my form even with ajax

Comment: I intend to add other input types as soon I get this one working.

Comment: @Badis consider making your Bean Viewscoped rather than requestscoped.

Comment: yes Zhedar that's what I have found on other stackoverflow questions,
But this controller is already on @ViewScoped ..

Comment: thank you Zhedar I solved the problem I just had to remove the postconstruct function ...